# Windows 10 - different icons and font after scaling?

Tags: windows-10, icons, scaling, 4k-resolution, high-resolution

Never would have thought, but I think I'm running out of keywords to search for on Google.
Here's what bothers me: There are two monitors involved. One has a resolution of 2560x1440 and the other 3840x2160. I have Windows 10 Pro N running and noticed that my 4k monitor displays different icons than my 2k monitor does. For example:

[[image: Pic Explorer icons at 2560x1440]]

Explorer icons at 2560x1440

[[image: Pic Explorer icons at 3840x2160]]

Explorer icons at 3840x2160

I thought all the new Windows icons were suitable for high resolutions (and 1440p isn't a potatoe resolution, is it?). It appeared to me that the font is also a different one on the 4k monitor. The 4k monitor displays Segoe UI while the 2k monitor displays the old Tahoma.

I've researched the problem but couldn't find anyone wondering about the icon-thing. And regarding the font I could only find people who wanted to go back to Tahoma because they didn't like the new Segoe UI font but not the other way around.

What I was able to figure out is that Windows changes the icons if I set the scaling to 125% or above. The 4k monitor is at 150% scaling, the 2k monitor works with a normal 100%.

So why does Windows change the icons and font and how could I get the same icons and font no matter what scaling I've set? Maybe someone here has some insight knowledge to share about this behavior.

Thanks!